# Problema programa c que usa hilos

Tags: c++, hilos

Realizar un programa con una variable entera global con un valor inicial de cero.
Crear un hilo que incremente la variable global en A unidades. Crear otro hilo que la disminuya en
B unidades. Al final el hilo principal(main) imprimirá el valor de la variable global.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <pthread.h>

using namespace std;

int a=0,A=0,B=0;

void *suma(void *data)
{
    int suma;
    struct timespec tiempo = { 5, 5};

    for(int i=0;i=A;i++)
    {
        a+=1;
        pthread_delay_np(&tiempo);  
        cout<<"El valor de a es:"<< a <<endl;
    }
}

void *resta(void *data)
{
    int resta;
    struct timespec tiempo = { 5, 5};

    for(int i=0;i=B;i++)
    {
        a-=1;
        pthread_delay_np(&tiempo);  
        cout<<"El valor de a es:"<< a <<endl;

    }
}

int main(void)
{
    pthread_attr_t atributos;

    cout<<"Valor de A a sumar:"<<endl;
    cin>>A;
    cout<<"Valor de B a restar:"<<endl;
    cin>>B;
    pthread_t proceso1; //Identificador de los hilos
    pthread_t proceso2;

    int pthread_create(pthread_t* proceso1, const pthread_attr_t *_NULL,void*(* suma)(void *),void*&a);// Crea el hilo, pone parametros por defecto, le muestra su rutina y el valor con el que va a ejecutar la rutina
    int pthread_create(pthread_t* proceso2, const pthread_attr_t *_NULL,void*(* resta)(void *),void*&a);
    pthread_join(proceso1,NULL);
    pthread_join(proceso2,NULL);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ¿ Cual es el problema ? ¿ Error de compilación ? ¿ Que error, en que línea ? ¿ O es de ejecución ? ¿ Lo obtenido no es lo esperado ? ¿ Que esperas, que obtienes ? Te sugiero consultar [¿ Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta ?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Un saludo.

Comment: no me sale ningun errror, pero al momento de ejecutarlo no me enseña los hilos trabajando esperando que se viera como suma y resta a "a" las veces que se lo pedi

Comment: Intente correr el código, pero me marco un error con los pthread_delay_np, aún así al cambiarlos por sleep(), el pthread_join me marca "Segmentation Fault", ¿saben como solucionarlo?